# Modify grafana query to skip one docker container

Tags: docker, grafana, prometheus, cadvisor

I am using Cadvisor to send metrics to Prometheus and show docker related graphs on Grafana using Cadvisor metrics

It shows all Docker container running on my machine but now I want to skip one container (cadvisor) from a list.

How can I achieve that?

for more details, I am sending a query which I am using to visualize

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should be able to achieve this with:

```
sort_desc(sum(rate(container_cpu_user_seconds_total{image!="",name!="some_container"}[1m])) by (name))
```

Where `some_container` is the name of the container that you don't want to include in the stats.

[Link to Prometheus query syntax](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/)

Comment: It is giving me following error,

__error:"parse error at char 52: unknown function with name "container_cpu_user_seconds_total""__

Comment: It is working, 

**sort_desc(sum(rate(container_cpu_user_seconds_total{image!="",name!="cadvisor"}[1m])) by (name))**

Comment: Oh, did I make a mistake in the prometheus query in my answer? I had to copy it "eye to hand" from the image that you supplied. What made the difference. And, I am glad you got it working. Best regards A

Comment: I see the issue, I put a `(` after the metric name. I fixed it in the answer.